# I am unable to search tree in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

table structure

```
userID    SponserID
102          200
201          102
202          102
203          201
```

all users have parend id means sponser ID
how to find all records which are which are userd of 102

pls help me

Comment: "find all records which are which are userd of 102"...? `SELECT ... WHERE userid = 102`? I think you might want to fix up your question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a real nested **tree** and are interested in finding *all children* of a particular node, not limited to direct children, you should start by reading this article: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Use these queries:

- For getting all records of userID 102

  `select * from tablename where userID=102`
- For getting all records where Parent is 102

  `select * from tablename where SponserID=102`